# Parsing JSON in swift 2.0

Tags: json, parsing, swift2

I'm trying to parse JSON data from a server api. 
The json :

```
    [
 {"interest": {
 "title":"Sport",
 "sub":[
        "painting",
        "photography",
        "museum"]
 }
 },
 {"interest": {
 "title": "music",
 "sub": [
         "rock",
         "classic",
         "techno"]
 }
 }]
```

The code to get it from a file just to test to parse it :

```
do{
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MainInterest", ofType: "json")
            let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
            let jsonResult:NSArray!  = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData! , options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
```

I can access the whole file with :

```
print(jsonResult)
```

But I can't access more than one level, here is the first level :

```
if let a = jsonResult {

        print(a[0]["interest"])
    }
```

I can then get my first object from my file, but **I would like to access** jsonResult[0]["interest"]["title"] (==Sport) or jsonResult[0]["interest"]["sub"][2] (== photography)  but I have this kind of error  build failed:

```
    Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?!' with an index of type 'String'
Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject?!' with an index of type 'Int'
```

Could you please help me ? I'm really stuck and the apple doc is not so explicite on this point I think. And I don't want to use framework like swiftyJson etc.

Thanks a lot ! 
Ben

**EDIT :**

Solved with (thanks @maxpovver) :

```
//To Get Title
        let title = (((self.interests as NSArray)[0] as? NSDictionary)?["interest"] as? NSDictionary)?["title"] as? NSString
        print(title)
        //To Get Sub
        let sub = ((((self.interests as NSArray)[0] as? NSDictionary)?["interest"] as? NSDictionary)?["sub"] as! NSArray)[1] as! NSString
```

Comment: there is no way u can dot it type safely.
as I remember the only way is smt like ((json["a"] as? Dictionary)["b"] as? NSArray)[0] etc

Comment: another example:
let maybeNumber = (((jsonObject as? NSDictionary)?["phoneNumbers"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["number"] as? NSString

Comment: Thank you @maxpovver , I try with : `//To Get Title
        let title = (((self.interests as NSArray)[0] as? NSDictionary)?["interest"] as? NSDictionary)?["title"] as? NSString
        print(title)
        //To Get Sub
        let sub = ((((self.interests as NSArray)[0] as? NSDictionary)?["interest"] as? NSDictionary)?["sub"] as! NSArray)[1] as! NSString`  and this finally worked, but that's right, I don't like to have this code in my project :-)

Comment: yes, but itt's the only way as swift does not have dynamic types @Benobab

Comment: I think you can remove this ugly NS prefix

Comment: If you solved it, post it as an answer and accept it... don't edit your _answer_ into your _question_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer

```
//To Get Title
    let title = (((self.interests as Array)[0] as? Dictionary)?["interest"] as? Dictionary)?["title"] as? String
    print(title)
    //To Get Sub
    let sub = ((((self.interests as Array)[0] as? Dictionary)?["interest"] as? Dictionary)?["sub"] as! Array)[1] as! String
```

Also can be made more readable:

```
let firstInterest = ((self.interests as Array)[0] as? Dictionary)?["interest"] as? Dictionary)?
let title = firstInterest?["title"] as? String
let sub = (firstInterest?["sub"] as! Array)[1] as! String
```

You'll never be ablo to simplify that without some extra libraries as swift does not support dynamic types.