# How to parse this specific JSON data in Swift 2.0

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, swift2

I'm trying to parse Json Data from an API :

```
{
    "title": "Mr. Robot",
    "first_aired": "2015-06-24",
    "network": "USA Network",
    "channels": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "USA",
            "short_name": "usa",
            "channel_type": "television"
 }
    ],
```

The Code I'm use is:

```
    var TVArray : [TVInfo] = []

    var task : NSURLSessionTask?


    func getJSON (urlString: String) {

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if (error == nil) {
                    self.updateJSON(data)
                }
                else {

                }
            }
        }
        task!.resume()
    }


    func updateJSON (data: NSData!) {

        let JSONData = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []))

        TVArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        if let jsonArray = JSONData {
            for j in jsonArray {
                let title = jsonResult["title"] as! String
                let firstAired = jsonResult["first_aired"] as! String
                let network = jsonResult["network"] as! String
                let channelName = JsonResult["channels"][0]["name"] as! String

                let TV = TVInfo(title: title, firstAired: firstAired, network: network,    channelName: channelName)

                TVArray.append(TV)
            }
        }

        collectionview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

When I use the above code I get an error 'Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'AnyObject'' in front of the line 'if let jsonArray = JsonData'. I've tried some methods I've seen on StackOverflow like the method in the link :
[[Parsing JSON in swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593594/parsing-json-in-swift-2-0#])
but it didn't work for me.  I'm still a bit new to Swift, I really don't want to use SwiftyJSON. Is this the best way to parse this JSON data or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Care to share the statement that causes the error?

Comment: Hint: In Xcode you can re-indent code by selecting it and control-i. Good indenting can make the code easier to understand.

Comment: It's the line :    if let jsonArray = JSONData {
        for j in jsonArray {
    let title = jsonResult["title"] as! String ....}

Comment: Thanks for that indention tip

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used NSJSONSerialization with `try!` *(note the `!`, meaning it was forced)* the value of `JSONData` is not an optional: you don't have to unwrap it with `if let jsonArray = JSONData`.

If you still want an optional value, use `try?` instead.

Otherwise you could also use `try` inside a `do catch` block to handle possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `JSONData` is unknown, it needs to be known to be an Array for the following for loop.

use:

```
let JSONData = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as! NSArray
```

You do not need:

```
if let jsonArray = JSONData {
```

because you have already crashed if JSONData is nil from the preceding `try!`

You are better with:

```
do {
    let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as! NSArray
    for j in jsonArray {
        // ...
    }
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

Because you have no control over the JSON you receive and crashing because of a server change is not a good idea.

Also really put some time into naming variables, `JSONData` is not data, it is an array obtained by parsing a JSON string.

Comment: I tried using the code you showed but for some strange reason on the "for j in jsonArray"  line there is an error 'Use of unresolved identifier 'jsonArray''.  Strange because i know in the line above it jsonArray is given a value.